# Error while executing multiple update query

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters

I am currently executing 20,000+ update queries. While executing I am facing lot of errors whenever it encounters special characters. Is there a way that I can identify for which update query there was an error. As for '&' I will add set define off but other characters I need to manually perform substitution or find a way.
update table set title = 'Mark & spencer's' where id ='1001';

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Where are the 20,000+ update queries coming from?  If it was me, I would go to the source where those update queries are generated and fix the output there so that valid statements are generated

Comment: I am currently running it on sq developer and I have those added in an excel sheet. I also wanted to identify which all rows are successful

Comment: I do similar things all the time (as in, I guess you've got a handful of columns and you're concatenating them with the relevant text to make a full UPDATE statement) - my suggestion is still to go to the source (ie. the Excel formula) and deal with any special characters (like single quotes) in the formula.  (You only need to do it for one formula, of course, then just copy and paste down)

Comment: I agree with you. But sometimes it might be a case where certain special character we might miss to identify. Also I am not  suppose to replace the character and how to tell Oracle to include that special character while updating.

Comment: check out the oracle q-quote syntax for escaping special characters in strings.

Comment: @Craig- I do not have these special characters in all rows. Could be 5,000 rows